# pass data from web server and show it on viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, http-post, segue

I have data from a server which I need to show on another View Controller.
**Note** I had perform a POST request.
**Note** I have 2 ViewControllers

these are the fields:

firstName

lastName

emailAddress

mobileNumber

This is the code that started the web service POST (data downloaded)

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let profileVC = segue.destination as? ProfileViewController else {return}
    profileVC.nameLabel.text = self.firstName
    profileVC.idNumberLabel.text = self.idNumber
    profileVC.emailAddressLabel.text = self.emailAddress
    profileVC.mobileNumberLabel.text = self.mobileNumber
```

This is where the downloaded data is supposed to show

```
private func updateUI(firstName: String, lastName: String, emailAddress: String, mobileNumber: String) {
    self.nameLabel.text = firstName + "" + lastName
    self.idNumberLabel.text = idNumber
    self.emailAddressLabel.text = emailAddress
       
}
```

this is the post request code

```
// Prepare URL
let url = URL(string: stringURL)
guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

// Prepare URL Request Object
var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// Set HTTP Request header
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("1088", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

// HTTP Parameters which will be sent in HTTP Request body
let postString = "userID=\(useridTextField.text)&password=\(passwordTextField.text)";

// Set HTTP Request Body
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

// Perform HTTP Request
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    
    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }
    
    do {
        var response = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
        response.idNumber = self.idNumber
        response.firstName = self.firstName
        response.middleName = self.middleName
        response.lastName = self.lastName
        response.emailAddress = self.emailAddress
        response.mobileNumber = self.mobileNumber
        response.landline = self.landline
        
        
        return
    } catch {
        let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        print(str)
        
    }
    
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: To pass data from your network service module to your view controller, you have several options such as the observer pattern using Notifications or you can look at the delegate pattern or something more recent which is like binding called Combine

Comment: any code will do thanks

Comment: Please could you add the code of your post request / function and then maybe I can try to create an example around that.

Comment: i'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Publish/Observer pattern with `Notifications`

I start with this simple extension that helps me organize notification names

```
extension Notification.Name {

    static let DidLoginSuccessfully
        = Notification.Name("DidLoginSuccessfully")
}
```

Let's say you have a Network class with a launch request function that launches your network request.

Once you have successfully got a response and decoded your response to a URL object, you can publish / post a notification to any observers

```
fileprivate func launchRequest() {
    
    // Prepare URL
    let url = URL(string: stringURL)
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

    // Prepare URL Request Object
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // Set HTTP Request header
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("1088", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    // HTTP Parameters which will be sent in HTTP Request body
    let postString = "userID=\(useridTextField.text)&password=\(passwordTextField.text)";

    // Set HTTP Request Body
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    // Perform HTTP Request
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            // Change response variable name to user
            var user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            user.idNumber = self.idNumber
            user.firstName = self.firstName
            user.middleName = self.middleName
            user.lastName = self.lastName
            user.emailAddress = self.emailAddress
            user.mobileNumber = self.mobileNumber
            user.landline = self.landline
            
            // Publish the notification
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .DidLoginSuccessfully,
                                            object: user)
            
            
        } catch {
            let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
            print(str)
            
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

Then in the module where you need some data to be updated, you need to observe / listen this notification

For example, let's say this was a view controller, you need to observe this notification and when you get notified of this event, you need to manage this.

```
class SomeCustomVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        subscribeToNotifications()
    }
    
    deinit {
        unsubscribeFromNotifications()
    }
    
    
    private func subscribeToNotifications() {
        
        // Sets the view controller to list to this notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(didLoginSuccessfully(_:)),
                                               name: .DidLoginSuccessfully,
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    // Your button login event handler
    private func didTapLoginButton() {
        // Make the segue or API request as you do
    }
    
    private func unsubscribeFromNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: .DidLoginSuccessfully,
                                                  object: nil)
    }
    
    // Your update UI function
    private func updateUI(firstName: String,
                          lastName: String,
                          emailAddress: String,
                          mobileNumber: String) {
        self.nameLabel.text = firstName + "" + lastName
        self.idNumberLabel.text = idNumber
        self.emailAddressLabel.text = emailAddress
    }
}

// Notification Observer
extension SomeCustomVC {
    
    @objc func didLoginSuccessfully(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        if let user = notification.object as? User {
            
            updateUI(firstName: user.firstName,
                     lastName: user.lastName,
                     emailAddress: user.emailAddress,
                     mobileNumber: user.mobileNumber)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Give this a go and see if it helps you.

If you are looking for something more sophisticated like binding, you can have a look at this [Combine tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAKco9XaPgg&ab_channel=SwiftArcade).